# Center a text in a div and make the table responsive

Tags: html, responsive-design, html-table, valign

I have a two difficulties in my code and thanks in advance for the people that can help me. I want to center my text in the background grey. I achieve to put in the middle by adding this lines of code:

```
line-height: 90px;
  text-align: center;
```

But when I do so certain part of my text in the div disappear and I don't know why. Plus I wanted to have advice because I would like to make this table responsive. My goal is that each cell act as a block and go one under another but I'm not sure if with my actual code if this is possible.

```css
table{
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Varela Round';
}

th, td {
  overflow:hidden;
  font-family: 'Varela Round';
  width:100%;
}

th{line-height:3;}
td{line-height:1.4;}

#base{background-color:#07183D;color:white;font-family: 'Varela Round';}
#intermediaire{background-color:#8A012C;color:white;font-family: 'Varela Round';}
#avance{background-color:#022C8A;color:white;font-family: 'Varela Round';}
#complet{background-color:#3B570A;color:white;font-family: 'Varela Round';}

.title600{font-size:18px; letter-spacing:1.5px;}
```

```html
<table>
   <tr>
      <th><center><div id="base" style="z-index: 1000; width: 258px; opacity: 1; transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);">
        <h2 class="title600">BASE</h2>
        </div></center></th>
      <th><center><div id="intermediaire" style="z-index: 1000; width: 258px; opacity: 1; transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);">
        <h2 class="title600">INTERMÉDIAIRE</h2>
        </div></center></th>
      <th><center><div id="avance" style="z-index: 1000; width: 258px; opacity: 1; transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);">
        <h2 class="title600">AVANCÉ</h2>
        </div></center></th>
      <th><center><div id="complet" style="z-index: 1000; width: 258px; opacity: 1; transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);">
        <h2 class="title600">COMPLET</h2>
        </div></center></th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td><center><div style="width:258px;text-align:justify;font-size: 12px">Cette formule vous permet de connaître les entreprises présentes sur ce territoire et de le valider </div></center></td>
     <td><center><div style="width:258px;text-align:justify;font-size: 12px">texte</center></td>
     <td><center><div style="width:258px;text-align:justify;font-size: 12px">texte</center></td>
     <td><center><div style="width:258px;text-align:justify;font-size: 12px">texte</center></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td><center><div style="width:258px;height:100px;text-align:justify;background:grey;"><b>Inclut</b>: la liste des sociétés</div></center></td>
     <td><center><div style="width:258px; height:100px;text-align:justify;background:grey;"><b>Inclut</b>: la liste des société + les contacts</div></center></td>
     <td><center><div style="width:258px; height:100px;text-align:justify;background:grey;
 ;"><b>Inclut</b>: la liste des société + les contacts + les mails nominatifs</div></center></td>
     <td><center><div style="width:258px; height:100px;text-align:justify;background:grey;"><b>Inclut</b>: la liste des société + les contacts + les mails nominatifs + les lignes directes (fixes et/ou mobiles)</div></center></td>
   </tr></table>
```

Comment: Couldn't reproduce the issue. Please make sure the issue exist before posting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have inline styles set on the td's, its best practics to add the styles into the style sheet, this will make it far easier to see where the styles are coming from.

For responsive elements use CSS @media queries. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

```css
body{
 font-family: 'Varela Round';
} 
 table {
     width: 100%;
}
th{
 line-height:3;
 text-align: center;
}
th div {
   max-width: 258px;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
td{
 line-height:1.4;
 text-align: center;
}
td div {
  max-width: 258px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#base{
 background-color:
 #07183D;
 color:white;
}
#intermediaire{
 background-color:#8A012C;color:white;
}
#avance{
 background-color:#022C8A;
 color:white;
}
#complet{
 background-color:#3B570A;
 color:white;
}
.title600{
 font-size:18px; 
 letter-spacing:1.5px;
}
.grey {
    background: #CCC;
    max-width: 258px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
 th,td,tr{
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
 }
  
}
```

```html
<table>
   <tr>
      <th><div id="base">
        <h2 class="title600">BASE</h2>
        </div></th>
      <th><div id="intermediaire">
        <h2 class="title600">INTERMÉDIAIRE</h2>
        </div></th>
      <th><div id="avance">
        <h2 class="title600">AVANCÉ</h2>
        </div></th>
      <th><div id="complet"">
        <h2 class="title600">COMPLET</h2>
        </div></th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td><div>Cette formule vous permet de connaître les entreprises présentes sur ce territoire et de le valider </div></td>
     <td><div>texte</div></td>
     <td><div>texte</div></td>
     <td><div>texte</div></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td><div class="grey"><b>Inclut</b>: la liste des sociétés</div></td>
     <td><div class="grey"><b>Inclut</b>: la liste des société + les contacts</div></td>
     <td><div class="grey"><b>Inclut</b>: la liste des société + les contacts + les mails nominatifs</div></td>
     <td><div class="grey"><b>Inclut</b>: la liste des société + les contacts + les mails nominatifs + les lignes directes (fixes et/ou mobiles)</div></td>
   </tr></table>
```

Comment: At first I thought that it was working but in your response I've just noticed you erase my div with the specific width . I don't my text to cover all the cell that's why I put a div

Comment: you can add max-width on the divs

Comment: like max-with:258px?